# How to upgrade spring version along with maven dependencies automatically in intellij?

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea

I am using spring framework 3.x and want to upgrade it to 4.x. Here is my pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.goal</groupId>
    <artifactId>goalserver</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate-version>3.6.3.Final</hibernate-version>
        <commons-dbcp-version>1.4</commons-dbcp-version>
        <target.environment>dev</target.environment>
        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Spring framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Used for Hibernate4 LocalSessionFactoryBean -->
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Used for Hibernate4 LocalSessionFactoryBean -->
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
          <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xbean</groupId>
            <artifactId>xbean-spring</artifactId>
            <version>3.14</version>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.1</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>rome</groupId>
            <artifactId>rome</artifactId>
            <version>0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.1_3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
          <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
          <version>5.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons Upload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
                 <!-- Apache BasicDataSource -->
                 <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
                 <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
                 <version>${commons-dbcp-version}</version>
             </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons Upload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSTL for c: tag -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Jackson for json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate Validator - implementation of Bean Validation JSR 303-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180813</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>

        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <target.environment>prod</target.environment>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

I tried to upgrade the spring version by setting `<spring.version>4.1.6.release</spring.version>` but it seems after doing that the project does not provide any error during compile time but throws error in runtime when intellij tries to deploy the war file in tomcat. Any suggestion or how can I do that automatically/how to understand which dependencies will not work with 4.1.6 ?

Comment: You should check Spring resources about 3 → 4 migration. See e.g. https://spring.io/blog/2014/01/30/migrating-from-spring-framework-3-2-to-4-0-1

Comment: Read the migration guide and upgrade in smaller steps (3.1, 3.2, 4.0. 4.1) and read migration guide for each upgrade and before taking the next step verify if everything still works!. Skipping 4 or more versions is likely going to be troublesome and you also might need to upgrade other dependencies as well (due to unsupported anymore etc.).

Comment: The problem is, during compile time maven says everything is fine!

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the `pom.xml` is not enough. You have to go to the Maven panel and click `Reload All Maven Projects` (first icon on the left).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best option will be to.... wright unit/integration tests. Spring provides test support for each application  layer and you should not depend on IDE capabilities to run / tests /deploy jobs. CI is your friend.